# LaTeX: Can I output the toc without compiling the entire document?

Tags: table-of-contents, compiling

Often you have to adjust the table of contents manually.
With very large documents, it is then very time-consuming to compile the entire document each time just to be able to look at small adjustments to the table of contents.

Is there any way to tell LaTeX to compile only the toc and not the document?

Or maybe you can copy the toc file of the actual document, rename it to the jobname of a small test file and then let it compile, sort of without the associated document?

Comment: Put the `\tableofcontents` in its own `\include` (as well as the other subfiles) and use `\includeonly`. (well `\tableofcontents` doesn't have to be in its own `\include`, but at least the other files, and then use `\includeonly` if you want to change only portions of your document)

Comment: well the toc collects text from all over the document, so if the text changes you have to recompile the document.  But if you simply want to test the output, you can simply input it in some other document.